# How to solve $\ddot{y} + a_{1}\dot{y} + (a_{2}+a_{3}e^{-2a_{4}t})y = a_{5}e^{-a_{4}t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have been in trouble finding a general solution for the following differential equation. 
\begin{equation}
  \ddot{y} + a_{1}\dot{y} + (a_{2}+a_{3}e^{-2a_{4}t})y = a_{5}e^{-a_{4}t}
\end{equation}
with the following initial conditions:
\begin{equation}
  y(0) = \dot{y}(0)=0
\end{equation}
I have tried a few methods to solve this equation but none of them seems promising.

1. Variation of parameters: I need to know at least one particular solution to apply this method but I could not find one. Is there any method to find one? (Reference: Chapter$3.9.2.1$ of https://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/html/nonhomogsys_section.html)
2. Laplace transform: Let Y be the Laplace transform of y, then the Laplace transform of this equation is:
   \begin{equation}
      (s^{2}+a_{1}s+a_{2})Y(s) + a_{3}Y(s+2a_{4}) = \frac{a_{5}}{s+a_{4}}
     \end{equation}
   but I have no idea how to deal with $Y(s+2a_{4})$ term. Moreover, comparison of the first term and the RHS implies that $Y(s)$ has an order of $s^{-3}$ but comparison of the second term and the RHS implies that $Y(s+2a_{4})$ has an order of $s^{-1}$, which seems to be impossible...

I would appreciate if you could give me any piece of advice. Thank you.